# Windows Phone - Tombstoning

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, tombstoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WP7: Is it possible to intercept the backstack before the journal thumbnail is created/stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565798/wp7-is-it-possible-to-intercept-the-backstack-before-the-journal-thumbnail-is-c)

I have an app with personal data that should not be displayed in the task viewer of WP8 when the app is send to background.

My idea was to raise a black page in the `Application_Deactivated` event, but the UI only seems to update when the app is reactivated again, in the task viewer is still the old UI.

Do you have any ideas/solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There is no lifecycle event that you can 'hook into' before your application 'screenshot' is obtained for the fast-app switching UI. You are going to have to re-think your application.

However, +1 for actually coming up with a reasonable scenario for wanting to achieve this