# prevent showing app screenshot in application navigation in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

for a security critial app I need to prevent the phone making screenshots of the embedded browser control.

On Windows Phone, if you hold the back button pressed, the opened applications are shown with small preview images.

Is there any way to replace that image being used there by an own image. Or is it possible to exclude controls using a xaml syntax from beeing captured?

Thanks Holger

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7: Is it possible to intercept the backstack before the journal thumbnail is created/stored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565798/wp7-is-it-possible-to-intercept-the-backstack-before-the-journal-thumbnail-is-c)

Comment: right, thanks! Reading this, there is no way to intercept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 GDR 3 introduced a hidden property on the page object that you can use to prevent screenshots from being taken of that page. [Here is more detail](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/01/20/disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app&utm_reader=feedly)